# Generating shingles with synonyms in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, pattern-synonyms, shingles

I have a file of alternate spellings for the terms in my index. I want to produce bigrams containing those alternate spellings for particular terms. For example, I have `biriyani, biryani, briyani` in my alternate spellings csv file and my field contains the text `Chicken Biryani`. I want to be able to produce `chicken biryani, chicken biriyani, chicken briyani` tokens.

Now, if I use a whitespace tokenizer with a synonym filter, the following tokens are generated `chicken, biriyani, biryani, briyani` which is expected. Now if I apply a shingle filter then, the tokens generated are `chicken, chicken biryani, biryani, biryani biriyani, biriyani, biriyani briyani, briyani`. This token stream contains shingles of synonyms of the word itself which should not be there and it does not contain tokens with `chicken [alternate spellings of biryani]` like chicken biriyani or chicken briyani, etc. If I place shingle filter before the synonym filter, then it only adds synonym tokens for the unigram: `chicken, chicken biryani, biriyani, biryani, briyani`. Is there a way to generate tokens that contain synonyms at the same position as the original token, or in this case `chicken biryani, chicken biriyani, chicken briyani`

Sample settings for testing:

```html
PUT test_bigram
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "synonym": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
              "biriyani, biryani, briyani"
            ]
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym_analyzer": {
            "filter": [
              "synonym"
            ],
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "whitespace"
          },
          "shingle_synonym": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": [
              "shingle",
              "synonym"
            ]
          },
          "synonym_shingle": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": [
              "synonym",
              "shingle"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am running Elasticsearch 5.6